# How to play and pause audio in firebase recyclerview in android

Tags: android, firebase, android-mediaplayer, media-player

I am developing an app in which I have to fetch audio from firebase. I am using firebase recycler view. I am getting a problem that when I click the first song it plays good, but when I click second item then the first song's play button does not change and seekbar of first and second song changes.

Here is the code.

```
    holder.play_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String audioUrl3 = model.getMedia();

            if (!isPlaying){
                if (mPlayer!=null){
                    mPlayer.release();
                }
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Loading....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                isPlaying = true;
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(audioUrl3);
                mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

                mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mPlayer.reset();
                try {
                    mPlayer.setDataSource(mContext,uri);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
                try{
                    mPlayer.prepareAsync();

                }catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    holder.play_btn.setImageDrawable(holder.play_btn.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play));

                }
                mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        if(mPlayer.isPlaying()){
                            mPlayer.stop();
                        }
                        mPlayer.start();
                        holder.play_btn.setImageDrawable(holder.play_btn.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_pause));
                        holder.seekBar.setMax(mPlayer.getDuration());
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Playing...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        updateSeekBar(holder.seekBar);
                    }
                });

                mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        holder.play_btn.setImageDrawable(holder.play_btn.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play));
                        isPlaying = false;

                    }
                });
            }

            else {
                isPlaying=false;
                stopPlaying();
            }
        }

        private void stopPlaying() {
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer=null;
            holder.play_btn.setImageDrawable(holder.play_btn.getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_play));

        }
    });

}

private void updateSeekBar(final SeekBar seek) {

   try{
       int pos = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
       seek.setProgress(pos);
   }catch (Exception e){
   }

    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateSeekBar(seek);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1800);
}
```

Comment: After play, stop button work or not for same audio?

Comment: yes, it stops when clicks the pause button

Comment: ok then you store all buton in List<Button> then button click all button stop and selected positonb button play

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please elaborate a little